# Make the posts visible only to administrators in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-permissions

I have an administrator account in `Drupal 6` and I have a lot of posts. I have then created a new authenticated user. When I log in using the new account, I can see all the posts the admin had posted even though the account I'm logged is not administrator account. I want to specify what posts the new account can only see. Is it on how my posts were posted using the administrator account or how my new account is created. Is there a way I can manage the administrator posts such that only administrator accounts can see it? Guide me here.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) module:

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete permissions for each content type. Optionally you can enable per content access settings, so you can customize the access for each content node.